# Question about Involuntary matrix?

Tags: matrices

If A be a 2x2 matrix with real entries. If $A^2=I$, then which of the following statements are true?:

> If $A\ne\pm I_2$ then $|A|=-1$

I know a supporting example $\begin{pmatrix}01\\10\end{pmatrix}$ which satisfies all conditions, but I'm unsure is this is enough to prove the above statement.

> If $A\ne\pm I_2$ then $\operatorname{tr}(A)\ne0$

This statement is straightforward false because of above counterexample.

> $tr(A)=0$

this might be true as now A can be $I_2$

> $|A|=1$

this also might be true.

I now want to ask if Statement 2 explains 1, and if Statement 4 explains 3?

Comment: Involuntary: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Accidental_Tourist

Comment: @WillJagy idk what you meant?

Comment: you wrote involuntary in your title. Two different words, involuntary and involutory. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involuntary    and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involutory_matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first one is true:$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a&b\\
c&d\end{array}\right)$,then$A^2=1\Leftrightarrow\left\{\begin{array}{c}
a^2+bc=1\\
bc+d^2=1\\
b(a+d)=c(a+d)=0
\end{array}\right.$
so if $d=-a$,then$|A|=ad-bc=-a^2-bc=-1$,if $b=c=0$,then$a^2=d^2=1$,since $A\not=\pm I_2,a,d\in R$,then $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
0&-1\end{array}\right)$or$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-1&0\\
0&1\end{array}\right)$ either way $|A|=-1$

Answer (score 1):

If $A^2=I_2 $, then its eigenvalues satisfy $\lambda^2=1$, so $\lambda=\pm1$. So the Jordan form of $A $ is either $\begin {bmatrix}\pm1&0\\0&\pm1\end {bmatrix} $ or $\begin {bmatrix}\pm1&1\\0&\pm1\end {bmatrix}$. In the second case, it is easy to check that such a matrix never satisfies $A^2=I $. So the Jordan form of $A $ is either $\pm I_2$, in which case $A=\pm I_2$, or $\begin {bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end {bmatrix} $; in this last case we have  $\det A=-1$ and $\text {tr}(A)=0$.